# convert date column datatype datetime64[ns] to text datatype

Tags: python, types

I want to convert date column datatype `datetime64[ns]` to text datatype in python (date is 07-07-2023) in this format

I used this:
`df['Start Date'] = pd.datetime(df['Start Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

and it is throwing an error

> 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.